# fwrite - Create text file but set extension to 'unl'

Tags: php, fwrite

I need to generate a unl file, which is for police reporting on foreign guest's in a hotel. I've looked into `fwrite`, but I'm not sure if that allows to set custom extension. I need the file to be `$name`.unl Below is the file structure, utf8 and pipes to divide data.

```
A|2|200500121222|VODPO|Hotel Pošta|Jan Sibelius, tel: 261 197 135|Strakonice|Vodňany|Vodňany I|Alešova|26||38901|2005.09.16 14:31:26||
U|01.10.2015|01.10.2015|Příjmení|Jméno||01.01.2000|||STP|bydliště|DOKLAD|VISUM|00||
U|01.10.2015|02.10.2015|ABDALLA|FAZUL||25.02.1974|||XXX|Kábul|321654|999|01||
U|01.10.2015|03.10.2015|ABDULLAH|MOHAMED||15.01.1977|||SYR|Damašek|987654|123|02||
U|01.10.2015|04.10.2015|AGOVIČ|MOHAMED||13.06.1970|||SCG|Noar|753159|321|03||
U|01.10.2015|05.10.2015|ANDĚL|JAN||01.01.1950|||BLZ|Brudé|159753|888|04||
U|01.10.2015|06.10.2015|HOHOS|KOKO||00.00.1950|||AFG|Kábul|123456|777|05||
U|01.10.2015|07.10.2015|SCHINDLER|BRUNO||00.00.2000|||DEU|Berlín|159753|666|06||
```

Would it be possible with `fwrite` or do I need to use something else?

Comment: When you `fopen()` a file, PHP doesn't care what extension you give it, it can be `.unl` or `.txt` or `.xls` or even no extension at all.... as far as PHP is concerned, it's simply a filename, and has no special meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that by using , `fopen` and `fwrite` in the following way:

```
<?php
$data = 'Your data';
$file_name = $name.'.unl';
$file = fopen($file_name,"a");
echo fwrite($file,$data);
fclose($file);
```

read about `fwrite` and `fopen` below:

[fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

[fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: instead of using 'w' use 'a' to make extra data append to the file in a later stage.

Comment: @ErikDohmen changed it to `a`

Answer (score 0):

fwrite takes a resource handle as it's first argument. To get that handle, you'd normally call fopen - the first argument being the file name, 2nd being the mode e.g. w for write as below. Valid modes are listed on http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

You would then use the following to get the handle to use with fwrite:

$fp = fopen($name . 'unl', 'w');

In terms of whether there's a better method - you might also want to take a look at fputcsv ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php ) and use a delimiter of |